# route /author/{username} in laravel note work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4, laravel-7

Hi i call this url  http://127.0.0.1:8000/author/Tohidda and i see 404 not found error. i
use this route but not work!...my route and controlelr is

```
  Route::get('/author/{username}','UserController@author')->name('dashboard.author');
public function author(User $user , Course $course,$username)
{
    $courses = Learning::with('course')->take(1)->latest()->get();
    $categories = Category::where('parent','0')->get();
    return view('Home.dashboard.author',compact('categories','user','courses','course','favorites'));
}
```

note:Tohidda my username in users table

Comment: `laravel-4`, `laravel-5` or `laravel-7`? Does it show up in `php artisan route:list`? Have you tried `php artisan route:clear`?

Comment: it is note work!

Comment: You should get different error. One about not passing sufficient number of arguments to method.

Comment: not diffrent error

Answer (score 0):

The route is probably accessed correctly. Laravel raises a404 because it cannot find the user model. You are accessing the User with the username, while by default you should access it with the `id` of the user.

You can use the `name`, but you'll need to instruct laravel to do so. You need to define the `name` as the key.
See: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions